# Website responsible problem in mobile view

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive, mobile-website

[Why am i getting this extra margin to the right of the website in the mobile view?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsCuF.jpg)

see this website on mobile to see the problem
https://likithmeruvu.github.io/

problem is why am i getting the extra margin or space to my right of the website in mobile view can anyone help me with this

My Code
https://github.com/LikithMeruvu/LikithMeruvu.github.io

Comment: <div class="col-md-6">
          <img src="images/stphone.png" alt="Startuplogo" height="500" width=" 363" align="right" class="rotated1" id="phonepic">
        </div>
this image is overflowing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a problem with the image "images/stphone.png", the image is rotated and crossed the right border

you need to add overflow: hidden to get rid of that effect.

add overflow:hidden to the col-md-6 class that wraps the image

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g041u.png)

Answer (score 0):

your image logo(stphone.png) breaks the page and caused the gap
you need to add overflow: hidden to section#title (the parent) or the image parent itself.